# Variance of the binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, error

Suppose you use MC events to determine a selection efficiency.

Where the efficiency is defined by:

$$\epsilon = \frac{m}{n}$$

n is the number of fixed number of trials
m is the accepted numbers from that. Therefore $\epsilon$ is the number that we can efficiency.

Measuring the efficiency uncertainty from binomial distributions can be written as: 
 $$\sigma ^2  = \frac{\epsilon (1- \epsilon)}{n}$$

Now, If define a function which is,

$f = \frac{n-m}{m+n}$, and want to do the binomial ratio error, should i first consider the addition and subtraction error in the numerator and denominator  and then take the binomial ratio error?

What do you think is the best way to measure the uncertainty  of measuring the function $f$?

Any source of materials for reading, strategies to follow or a comprehensive answer would help.

Comment: Your $f$ seems likely to range from $-1$ to $0$.  Is that deliberate?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to write other way round.  Is it okay if i take absolute value during the computation? I'm saying this because we don't want to have imaginary number.

Comment: I have upated my answer for a closed formula of the variance of $f$ to reflect your change in its definition. Note that always $n\geq m$, so I do not understand why you would need an absolute value. Or do you refer to another expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible approaches. The most simple would be to apply Gauss' law of error propagation. In your case, it is
\begin{eqnarray*}& f(\epsilon) & =\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon+1}\\
\Rightarrow\quad & \sigma^2(f)&\approx \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\epsilon}\right)^2\cdot\sigma^2(\epsilon)=\left(\frac{2}{(\epsilon+1)^2}\right)^2\cdot \frac{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}{n}\end{eqnarray*}
As you are doing a MC simulation anyway and thus do not need a closed formula for the variance, you can alternatively try resampling estimators, like the *Jackknife* or the *Bootstrap* estimator of the variance. For a gentle introduction to the latter two, see

> Efron, Gong: "A leisurely look at the bootstrap, the jackknife, and cross-validation." The American Statistician 37.1 (1983): 36-48.